# How to bulk check in all checked out documents in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, document, checkout, bulk, checkin

I have SharePoint 2010 environment. Many documents are checked out by other users.

I need to bulk check-in those documents. Can anyone suggest to me a reliable way for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below PowerShell.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  
#Variables
$WebURL="http://domain/sites/emilytest"
$LibraryURL="/Shared%20Documents" #Relative URL of a folder or library
 
#Get Objects
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$Folder = $web.GetFolder($LibraryURL)
 
#Function to find all checked out files in a SharePoint library
Function CheckIn-CheckedOutFiles($Folder)
{
 
    $Folder.Files | Where { $_.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" }  | ForEach-Object {
    write-host ($_.Name,$_.URL,$_.CheckedOutBy)
 
    #To Check in
    $_.Checkin("Checked in by Administrator")
    }
 
   #Process all sub folders
   $Folder.SubFolders | ForEach-Object {
   CheckIn-CheckedOutFiles $_
   }
}
 
#Call the function to find checkedout files
CheckIn-CheckedOutFiles $Folder
```